# How do I get certain values at the end of my list, get these values every so often, and insert in certain positions in my original list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

Say I have a list like this:

```
ls = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14]
```

and I want to get the last six entries of this list by doing:

```
new_ls = ls[-6:]
```

From here, I want to get this new list and get every two of this `new_ls` and insert it between every two of my `ls` so that my output looks like:

```
output_ls = [a1,a2,a9,a10,a3,a4,a11,a12,a5,a6,a13,a14,a7,a8]
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

This is what I've tried so far in my code with total_ls having 108 elements:

```
new_ls1 = list(xy4b1.items())
new_ls2 = list(xy4b2.items())
total_ls = new_ls1 + new_ls2

size = 2
start = -36
test_ls = total_ls[start:start+size]

total_ls.insert(4,test_ls)
```

I could only get to inserting my "last elements" into my original list. I have not done the `for` loop implementation as I don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code

Comment: What have you tried, and how does it not work?
This is not a service for solving programming puzzles.

Comment: @James I've edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Prune. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python example with variable NewList additions at request:

```
ls = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10']
newList= ls[-4:]
ls = ls[0:len(ls)-4]
print(ls)
print(newList)
endList=[]
isPutFromNewList = True
amountToTakeFromNewList =2
amountOfOldListToHaveBetween=6
lsCounter=0;
newListCounter=0
i=0
while(len(endList)!=(len(ls)+len(newList))):
  if((i%amountOfOldListToHaveBetween==0 and not isPutFromNewList) or (i%amountToTakeFromNewList==0 and isPutFromNewList)):
    isPutFromNewList = not isPutFromNewList
  
  if(isPutFromNewList and newListCounter<len(newList)):
    endList.append(newList[newListCounter])
    newListCounter=newListCounter+1
  
  if(not isPutFromNewList and lsCounter<len(ls)):
    endList.append(ls[lsCounter])
    lsCounter=lsCounter+1
  i= i+1
  
print("end list:",endList)
```

JS Example below since I had fun writing it:

```js
var ls = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10'];
var newList= ls.slice(-4)
ls = ls.slice(0,ls.length-4)
console.log(ls);
console.log(newList);
var endList=[];
var isPutFromNewList = true;
var lsCounter=0;
var newListCounter=0;
for(var i=0 ;(endList.length!=(ls.length+newList.length));i++){
  if(i%2==0){
    isPutFromNewList = !isPutFromNewList;
  }
  if(isPutFromNewList && newListCounter<newList.length){
    endList.push(newList[newListCounter]);
    newListCounter++;
  }
  
  if(! isPutFromNewList && lsCounter<ls.length){
    endList.push(ls[lsCounter]);
    lsCounter++;
  }
  
}
console.log("end list:",endList);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the language is python.

Comment: @NikNack fixed <3

Comment: @StarshipladDec Thank you so much! Very helpful! Clarifying question though, if I had a list that was 108 elements long and I wanted to make the newList be the last 36 elements of this list, and from here, insert the groupings of two from the new list every 6 into the original list, what would I modify to make this every 6 elements in the original list? Thanks!

Comment: You are being very helpful with my question. I appreciate it! If you could help me with my comment, I'd very much appreciate it and mark this as answered. Glad you're having fun! <3

Comment: I've updated my example to further reflect what I'm talking about. Sorry for the spam.

Comment: @NikNack rather than 
`if(i%2==0):
    isPutFromNewList = not isPutFromNewList
  `
Try use :
`everyoriginalList=6
groupsOfNewList=2
...
#BELOW: If you need to start adding from newList
if(i%everyoriginalList==0 and not isPutFromNewList ):
    isPutFromNewList = not isPutFromNewList
#BELOW: If you've just added your nth NewList element
elif(i%groupsOfNewList==0 and not isPutFromNewList ):
    isPutFromNewList = not isPutFromNewList`

Comment: @NikNack all good homie. There will be more efficient/ code-lite ways of doing this, but it's what works and it gives a good indication as to what is actually happening.
I'd reccomend putting the code into a function, with `OldListStepsBetween` and `ammountOfNewListToPlace` as parameters

Comment: @marc-s thanks for the edit, if you want an un-paid fulltime role correcting my silly spelling mistakes, DM me! <3